# My Apache Require expr RegEx is not working

Tags: regex, apache, require

Apache 2.4.17

I have noticed a lot of attempts to hack the site e.g.

> POST `/?q=/user/password&name[%23post_render][0]=passthru&name[%23markup]=powershell%20-Command%20%22Start-Process%20-Filepath%20%27%25Temp%25%5Czwtaskhost.exe%27%22 HTTP/1.1`

and

> POST `/?q=/file/ajax/name/%23value/form-lahkvnivQIIoPelIsDem7RCESjCUXunYli_RdiErQZI HTTP/1.1`

I am trying yo block this access using

```
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted    
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#/file/ajax/name(.*)#
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#/user/password\&name(.*)#
  </RequireAll> 
</Directory>
```

Can someone explain why these expr is not working?
Is there any way to trace the flow through such a block to see what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to block some query string. Try these directives:

```
<RequireAll>
   Require all granted    
   Require expr "!(%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#/file/ajax/name#)"
   Require expr "!(%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#/user/password&name#)"
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: I should have stated that I did try QUERY_STRING to no avail. I added your  lines just in case but it has not blocked the HTTP requests.

Comment: Just for testing I added this code in my .htaccess and then requested `http://localhost/?q=/file/ajax/name` URI and it returned `403 Forbidden` error so it worked as expected.

Comment: http://localhost/q=/file/ajax/name (without ?) does block, with /?q does not block. Both these are using the GET method. The hacker is using POST.

Comment: Not without `?` I have tested it as query string with the URL exactly as shown in my previous comment and it worked.